# Is there a way to customize JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Swing and working on Minesweeper application. I'm trying to layout the header field correctly and the issue is I don't reaaly understand what kind of font I should use for displaying the counts of mines and time:

[image]

How to customize JLabel this way or is there another possible solution? I would be appriciate any ideas...

Comment: All Swing components can be customized throught inheritence and redefining the paint method, you can read more at this link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Comment: Better to find or create 10 ImageIcons to correspond to the 10 possible number digits, to use 3 JLabels in a GridLayout, and swap icons.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sounds good, thank you.

Comment: Note that it's called a "seven segment" or LED display.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels BTW, don't you know if there's some more-or-less similar font to LED in the picture?

Comment: @user3663882: not as part of standard Java, but it would be easy to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's [some Digital Clock Fonts](http://www.1001fonts.com/digital+clock-fonts.html) that can be useful (the first one, `Digital-7 +3`, is the one in the picture):

[image]

To get the same result you need to modify the background color and the font color & size to requirement.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here, what's the difference please ? and the font will give him the exact apparence that he's looking for

Comment: (1+) I think its a good answer. It answers the question by specifying a custom Font that can be used, instead of doing custom painting. So it give the OP a choice of solution they prefer. To me all questions should have an "accepted" answer. If you post this as a comment then the question will always appear that it has never been answered. When I search the forum, I like to save time by looking at questions with answers.

Comment: @camickr *"I like to save time by looking at questions with answers."* I just commented to trashgod that I tend not to follow links in search results, unless the question has an *accepted* answer (yes - *very* fussy).